# :How to create a event in c# without delegates?

Tags: c#, events

I tried like this but it will return null values,

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> myevent;


public void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (myevent!= null)  //Here I get null value.
        myevent(null, new EventArgs());
}
```

How to achieve the event fire?

**Edit:**

I have a `UserControl` in that user control which contain button event,inside the ButtonClick method I created this event.

I have a `Form`. In that form i m using this UserControl. So i need to Fire a event from User Control button click event to Form page particular function.

Comment: cause there is no one registered with your event

Comment: You haven't registered any handler method to your event, what do you expect to run when you raise it?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events

Comment: The below link will be helpful to your question:
[Events With or Without Delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334736/events-with-and-without-delegates-in-asp-net)

Comment: @SelmanGenc event fire to another class and specific method(Windows forms).mypage.myevent+= MainPage_InfoClick; ;

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a very simple, and basic solution for you. Please read the comments in the code to make sense of the solution. If anything is unclear, please ask questions.

Below sample, will cause the event to fire, if the person's name changes:

Here is the Person object:

```
public class Person
{
    //Event to register to, when you want to capture name changed of person
    public event EventHandler<NameChangedEventArgs> nameChangedEvent;

    //Property
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            this._name = value;
            //Call the event. This will trigger the OnNameChangedEvent_Handler
            OnNameChangedEvent_Handler(new NameChangedEventArgs() {NewName = value});
        }
    }

    private void OnNameChangedEvent_Handler(NameChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        //Check if event is null, if not, invoke it.
        nameChangedEvent?.Invoke(this, args);
    }
}

//Custom event arguments class. This is the argument type passed to your handler, that will contain the new values/changed values
public class NameChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string NewName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code that instantiates and uses the Person object:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Instantiate person object
        var person = new Person();
        //Give it a default name
        person.Name = "Andrew";

        //Register to the nameChangedEvent, and tell it what to do if the person's name changes
        person.nameChangedEvent += (sender, nameChangedArgs) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nameChangedArgs.NewName);
        };

        //This will trigger the nameChanged event.
        person.Name = "NewAndrewName";

        Console.ReadKey();


    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this concepts to my code but event not getting fire

Answer (score 0):

can you please try the below way of calling event :

```
public event EventHandler myevent;
myevent += new  EventHandler(Button1_Click);

        if (myevent != null)  //Here I get null value.
            myevent(1, new EventArgs());
```