# What's the difference between using or not using delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I have some doubt of understanding the concept of using delegate, below is the delegate example that I have.

This example is using a Photo filtering software as a instance, which will add filter to a photo and using delegate will increase the flexibility of adding new filter in the future.

**Before using Delegate**

Photo.cs:

```
 class Photo
    {
        private string path;

        public Photo(string path)
        {
            this.path = path;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} imported", path);
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} photo saved", this.path);
        }
    }
```

PhotoFilter.cs:

```
class PhotoFilter
{
    public void AddBrigtness(Photo photo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Added Brightness");
    }

    public void AddFilter(Photo photo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Added Filter");
    }

    public void AddShadow(Photo photo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Added Shadow");
    }
}
```

PhotoProcesser.cs:

```
class PhotoProcesser
{
   public void Process(string path)
    {
        var photo = new Photo(path);
        var filter = new PhotoFilter();

        filter.AddBrigtness(photo);
        filter.AddFilter(photo);
        filter.AddShadow(photo);

        photo.Save();
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var process = new PhotoProcesser();
        process.Process("123.jpg");
    }
}
```

**After using Delegate**

*** *Photo.cs* and *PhotoFilter.cs* are remain unchanged

PhotoProcesser.cs:

```
 delegate void PhotoMethodHandler(Photo p); // Delegate

    class PhotoProcesser
    {
       public void Process(string path,PhotoMethodHandler methodHandler)
        {
            var photo = new Photo(path);

            methodHandler(photo);

            photo.Save();
        }
    }
```

Program.cs:

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var filter = new PhotoFilter();

            PhotoMethodHandler p = filter.AddBrigtness;
            p += filter.AddFilter;
            p += RemoveRedEyeFilter; // To simulate the flexibility of using Delegate

            var process = new PhotoProcesser();
            process.Process("123.jpg",p);
        }

        static void RemoveRedEyeFilter(Photo photo) // Newly added filter
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Added RemoveRedEye");
        }
    }
```

Output:

[image]

At this point, I can understand the flexibility of using Delegate as a Function pointer, 
but if we are thinking in another way, we also can get the same result if we don't use the PhotoProcesser.cs and change the Program.cs as below:

Program.cs:

```
  class Program
    {    
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var photo = new Photo("p1.jpg");
            var filter = new PhotoFilter();

            filter.AddBrigtness(photo);
            filter.AddFilter(photo);
            RemoveRedEyeFilter(photo);

            photo.Save();

        }

        static void RemoveRedEyeFilter(Photo photo) // Newly added filter
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Added RemoveRedEye");
        }
    }
```

Output:

[image]

It will get the same outcome and the same flexibility *(To add a new filter in this case)* as using of delegate.

As per above example,could anyone can give me some direction to understand what is the benefit/different of using delegate? Thanks!

Comment: this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334736/events-with-and-without-delegates-in-asp-net

Comment: EventHandler is a child of Delegate, so the case is different. As per the example, I am confusing when and why I should use Delegate?

Comment: In term of re-usability, using delegate can reduce some codes if we need to process the same action multiple times. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind delegates (and with lambda or any pointer to a function) is to be able to transfer a static behaviour (defined by code) to dynamic (defined by data).

For instance I could do :

```
Photo p = new Photo();
p = ApplyX(p);
p = ApplyY(p);
...
```

But with delegate I can do

```
List<Func<Photo,Photo>> filters = Whatever();
Photo p = new Photo();
foreach(var filter in filters)
{
   p = filter(p);
}
```

This would let you change the list of filters at runtime (by inserting and removing delegate in the filters list).

You can check this for further reading: [Open Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)